# Error installing Unity nuget package in Windows Phone 8.1 app project

Tags: nuget, unity-container

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

File -> New Project -> Blank App (Universal Windows 8.1)

This creates a solution with 3 projects: a Windows 8.1 project, a Windows Phone 8.1 project and a Shared project.

If I try to install the Unity nuget package I get following error

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 3.1.1.0

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> Install-Package Unity -Version 3.5.1404
Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Unity.3.5.1404' with respect to project 'App3\App3.WindowsPhone', targeting 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Unity.3.5.1404' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Unity.3.5.1404'
Resolved actions to install package 'Unity.3.5.1404'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Unity 3.5.1404' does not exist in project 'App3.WindowsPhone'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Unity 3.5.1404'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with 
that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Unity -Version 3.5.1404
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

Unity installs without error into the Windows 8.1 project.

How do I resolve this issue?

UPDATE: 16/9/2015
I get same behaviour on my work PC running Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2013.

UPDATE: 17/09/2015 
Set nuget to show pre-release packages then install Unity 3.5.1405-prerelease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unity NuGet package version 3.5.1404 does not support Universal Windows Projects.

It does support Windows Phone Silverlight projects.

If you create a Windows Phone Silverlight project you can install the Unity NuGet package into it.

Comment: I installed version 3.5.1405-prerelease with following nuget command:     `Install-Package Unity -Pre`

Comment: I can install Unity into both projecs by using the following nuget command:     `Install-Package Unity -Pre`   This installs version 3.5.1405-prerelease.  I'm sure version 3.5.1404 should support Windows Phone as it is tagged on the nuget page [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/3.5.1404)

Comment: Version 3.5.1404 does not support Universal Windows Phone projects it only supports Windows Phone Silverlight projects. In the 3.5.1405-prerelease they changed the profile of the Portable Class Library assembly so it includes (wpa) which is what NuGet uses to refer to Universal Windows Phone projects. The stable version does not have a PCL that supports wpa.

Comment: Ok fair enough @MattWard.  I watched [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/DEV-B213) in which Jerry Nixon shows adding Unity to Win Phone 8.1 app & assumed he was adding latest stable version (see 58:20) but on pausing video he has set include pre-releases

Comment: By default nuget in visual studio doesn't show pre-release packages.  Pity he didn't mention this in the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I can install unity into both projects by the following nuget command:

`Install-Package Unity -Pre`

This installs version 3.5.1405-prerelease.  According to nuget page for Unity both WindowsPhone and WindowsPhone8 are listed in the tags section.